# Non-capturing group not working in Regex

Tags: .net, regex

Using regex, I want to match the following strings:

```
January 25
Jan 25
```

I'm capturing month and date parts separately but want to return only the first 3 characters of month name if there's full month name, so I'm using non-capturing group `(?:)` for the characters "uary":

```
(?<M>(Jan(?:uary)?)) (?<D>\d\d)
```

Unfortunately, the group `M` always returns full month name; i.e. it captures the non-capturing group too.

I have already turned on ExplicitCapture flag. I've used both RegExBuilder and Rad Software's Regular Expression Designer to make sure it is not because of the tool.

Comment: Which language? Regular expressions come in several different flavours and different host languages use different flavours.

Comment: This is .NET Fx. (4.0 if that matters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your capturing group should surround only  `Jan`.

```
(?<M>Jan)(?:uary)? (?<D>\d{1,2})
```

Your original expression is roughly equivalent to `(?<M>January|Jan) (?<D>\d\d)`. The non-capturing group does not mean that the match is removed from existing capturing groups. It means only that no new capturing group is created.

Comment: Thanks for being quick, accurate and informative Mark. This explanation is as helpful as your answer.

Comment: The only issue I see is that it will only match when there are 2 digits in the day. last group should be    `(?<D>\d{1,2})`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?<M>Jan)(?:uary)? (?<D>\d\d)
```